# How do I remove the proper subsets from a list of sets in Scala?

Tags: scala, graph

I have a list of sets of integers as followed: {(1, 0), (0, 1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4)}.

I want to write a program in Scala to remove the sets that are proper subset of some set in the given list, i.e. the final result would be: {(0,1,2), (1,2,3,4,5)}.

An O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution can be done by checking each set against the entire list but that would be very expensive and does not scale very well for ~100000 sets. I also thought of generating edges from the sets, remove duplicate edges and run a DFS but I have no idea how to do it in Scala (the more Scala-ish way and not one-to-one from Java code).

Answer (score 2):

Individual elements (sets) need only be compared to other elements of the same size or larger.

```
val ss = List(Set(1, 0), Set(0, 1, 2), Set(1, 2), Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Set(3, 4))

ss.sortBy(- _.size) match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case hd::tl =>
      tl.foldLeft(List(hd)){case (acc, s) =>
        if (acc.exists(s.forall(_))) acc
        else s::acc
      }
  }
//res0: List[Set[Int]] = List(Set(0, 1, 2), Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me some time to understand, but this is so clean and succinct.